# R list top n entries in a dataframe by factor or integer

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe, rank

I would like to list the top n entries in a dataframe for each level of a factor or an integer. Here is the code I have:

```
index <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3)
prob <- runif(20,0,1)

x.df <- data.frame(cbind(index,prob))
x.df <- x.df[order(x.df$index,-x.df$prob),]

head(x.df[x.df$index==1,],n=3)
head(x.df[x.df$index==2,],n=3)
head(x.df[x.df$index==3,],n=3)
```

This does the job, but I'd like to not have to explicitly have a head statement for every level/integer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In base R, there is by group method called `tapply`:

```
with(x.df, stack(tapply(prob, index, head, 3)))
#     values ind
#1 0.9045300   1
#2 0.7651376   1
#3 0.3631891   1
#4 0.9471318   2
#5 0.9206743   2
#6 0.7675069   2
#7 0.9866379   3
#8 0.9149754   3
#9 0.7862320   3
```

And there is also the `by` function for `data.frame`:

```
do.call(rbind, by(x.df, index, head, 3))
```

which yields  the same result

Comment: Thanks, I'll go with this solution - I prefer base R for stuff, even if it's a bit slower.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your dataframe is order in a way you want, then you can do this:

```
library(dplyr)

x.df %>%
  group_by(index) %>%  # for each index
  slice(1:3) %>%       # get top 3 rows
  ungroup()            # forget the grouping

# # A tibble: 9 x 2
#   index  prob
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1 0.943
# 2     1 0.461
# 3     1 0.251
# 4     2 0.739
# 5     2 0.697
# 6     2 0.695
# 7     3 0.968
# 8     3 0.915
# 9     3 0.635
```

Comment: This won't sort rows, I think you want `top_n`

Comment: No it won't. I've specified that as an assumption on top of my answer. Not clear to me if "top n entries" always means "top probabilities". "Top n" entries in general means top n rows.

Comment: Oh sorry I've skimmed too fast, as OP sorted the rows I assumed it should be part of the solution but I get your point now, the question might start at the final `x.df` value

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's unordered

```
  x.df %>%           
      group_by(index) %>% 
      top_n(3) %>%
      ungroup()
```

Comment: `top_n` sorts the rows, you don't need `arrange`

Answer (score 1):

Easy solution using `data.table` package-

```
> setDT(x.df)[,head(.SD,3),by=index]
```

**Output**-

```
index      prob
1:     1 0.7863076
2:     1 0.7103228
3:     1 0.5657803
4:     2 0.9939695
5:     2 0.7517839
6:     2 0.7348664
7:     3 0.9260537
8:     3 0.5889305
9:     3 0.5557626
```

**Note**- If your `prob` is not ordered then use this-

```
> setDT(x.df)[order(-prob),head(.SD,3),by=index]
```